# Tailwind/Vue dynamicaly align flex items to same high as neighbor

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox, tailwind-css

i want to have a following grid of elements using flex, tailwind & vue:
[image]

I get alot of items from a backend and i want to display each item within a flex container next to each other, but only 2 items in one row. This should be easily to achive with justify-between and w-1/2 for each item. But the next requirement is, that the items next to each other take in the same height as the item with more content than the other. The heigh is now fixed here, only the margins. How can i do this?
I got a similar approach working but not with a dynamic number of items, only with a fixed number of items. But how can i achive this when i dont know how much items i will get?

My current approach:

```
<div class="mt-3 flex flex-row flex-1 flex-wrap justify-between">
  <div v-for="item in items"  class="w-1/2 mt-1.5">
    <div
      class="border border-solid rounded-lg border-black border-opacity-10"
    >
    The content for each item belongs here
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chunk the loop by 2 and then do the following. See [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/fIkTiuBAxY).

```
<div class="p-4 space-y-4">
  <div class="flex space-x-4">
    <div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum assumenda eaque veritatis, porro culpa reprehenderit nisi. Iusto labore ex culpa excepturi velit eos a consequatur beatae aliquam, vero quidem ut.Beatae dolores eligendi accusantium delectus fugiat ex iure vero quam doloribus quo sapiente, necessitatibus fuga! Voluptatibus eaque aut quis omnis magni dolorum iusto delectus laborum, nesciunt id quia praesentium rerum?</div>
    <div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">small content</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex space-x-4">
    <div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">small content</div>
    <div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ut quod voluptas nisi modi perspiciatis aliquid ad tempora cum corporis sapiente blanditiis dicta, esse reiciendis sed eveniet, libero, dignissimos perferendis.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex space-x-4">
    <div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates eum saepe natus, numquam quibusdam praesentium, incidunt debitis at, nihil similique quidem doloribus? Natus delectus vero quidem, autem fugiat amet odit. Maxime dolorum nostrum vitae adipisci, exercitationem corporis iure, repellat sunt quidem numquam voluptatem beatae dignissimos aliquid suscipit laboriosam modi quibusdam excepturi possimus voluptatibus voluptas deleniti maiores saepe atque doloremque. Totam. Fuga dignissimos ducimus dicta pariatur temporibus dolor commodi soluta. Expedita neque hic explicabo deleniti laudantium animi nesciunt aut vero. Deserunt, sint. Deleniti illum optio rem unde placeat ab eos fuga. Cumque illum odio, consequuntur repudiandae quis error fugit deserunt velit modi illo soluta nihil architecto, ex cum nesciunt, ad laboriosam. Ex nihil unde modi facere quibusdam, nesciunt quod aliquid voluptatum.</div>
    <div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni ut quod voluptas nisi modi perspiciatis aliquid ad tempora cum corporis sapiente blanditiis dicta, esse reiciendis sed eveniet, libero, dignissimos perferendis.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the layout looks exactly how i want it to be! But with your solution i struggle how to loop through my items to achive the exactly layout? Because after every two items i need to put another `<div class="flex space-x-4">` wrapper around my `<div class="flex w-1/2 border p-4">` items

Comment: Hi i fixed this with two seperate arrays and a index v-for loop. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can see sample code [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/lCr5a3rIYf).
For dynamic data, you can write as follows.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2">
  <div v-for="item in items">
   <div class="border p-4 rounded-lg m-3">
    A lot content
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This gives me the correct layout and is working with my iterations. 
But some pitfalls: Is it possible to use flex to structure my items? Because if i use any flex within my items, the side-by-side height of the grid container isnt working anymore. For example i use for my item the following `<div class="flex border  p-4 rounded-lg m-3">` instead `<div class="border p-4 rounded-lg m-3">`  the height isnt aligned to my side-by-side item anymore.

Comment: You can add flex class in the div tag. After adding flex class in my code sample, the bug doesn't occur. The height is aligned to side-by-side item. You can look [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/zzt31k7NUr).

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me with my full code. But i got it working know with the above accepted solution. Thank you!